# CodeIgniter & Datamapper - Two foreign keys to same field

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreign-keys, datamapper

I have a database with a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `flight_booking` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `flight_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `departure_airport_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `arrival_airport_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_flight_booking/departure_airport` (`departure_airport_id`),
  KEY `fk_flight_booking/arrival_airport` (`arrival_airport_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_flight_booking/arrival_airport` FOREIGN KEY (`arrival_airport_id`) REFERENCES `airport` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_flight_booking/departure_airport` FOREIGN KEY (`departure_airport_id`) REFERENCES `airport` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

So, a booking has 2 airports, an arrival and a departure one
Thing is, I can't figure out how to declare the relationship in my model.
I've tried different things, this is what I have right now:

```
    class flight_booking extends DataMapper {
        var $table = 'flight_booking';
        var $has_one = array (
                'flight',
                'departure_airport' => array (
                        'class' => 'airport'
                        ),
                'arrival_airport' => array (
                        'class' => 'airport',
                ) 
        );
var $validation = array (
            'id' => array (
                    'label' => 'ID',
                    'rules' => array () 
            ),

            'flight_id' => array (
                    'label' => 'Flight ID',
                    'rules' => array (
                            'required' 
                    ) 
            ),

'departure_airport_id' => array (
                    'label' => 'Departure airport id',
                    'rules' => array (
                            'required'
                    ) 
            ),
   'arrival_airport_id' => array (
                        'label' => 'Arrival aiport ID',
                        'rules' => array (
                                'required'
                        ) 
                )
    )
```

This gives me an "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your rule name: required." error when trying to save
Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, the ""Unable to access an error message corresponding to your rule name: required." had nothing to do with it. I fixed some bad declarations and now I just get an error telling my that my relationships aren't correctly designed